# unauthenticated error code calling api in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, restful-authentication

I'm working on Laravel RestFull Api, where this Api will consume by same application. When I call Api by using axios, I'm getting 401(unauthenticated)error code. Can anyone please tell me why is that and how to solve this issue?

Comment: what route you are using and also check the route you are using is uses any middleware if it is than you have to send authentication key

Comment: Can update your question with request headers ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Laravel Passport for your REST auth management. If that is the case:

If your API should be public accessable, just remove all middleware from your route. If you apply the `auth:api` middleware, you have to do the following:

To consume your own application via javascript, you have to include the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to your web middleware group:

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

This will attach the `laravel_token` cookie to your outgoing requests. Now you can simply call your endpoit with axios:

```
axios.get('/api/user')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Read more about it here: [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

actually everything was fine, only due to composer update laravel current version changed to newest one. That's why raise the problem. In composer.json file restrict the laravel version and did composer update again. So, now working good.